# mongoose - how to get a schema's final document without an insertion

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Say I have a schema like this.

```
{
    __content: {
        default: "",
        index: true,
        type: Mixed,
        validate: {
            validator(v)
            {
                return !!(
                    typeof v === "string" ||
                    (
                        typeof v === "object" &&
                        !Array.isArray(v)
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    },
    __hidden: {
        default: false,
        index: true,
        type: Boolean
    },
    __title: {
        required: true,
        index: true,
        type: String,
    },
    __type: {
        default: "text",
        enum: ["text", "table"],
        index: true,
        type: String
    },
}
```

Is it possible to return what the schema would be like if I made a blank insert e.g. `Model.create({})` without an actual insertion? Right now, my idea is to insert it into a throwaway collection and just get the return

Comment: Just initialize an instance of `Model`, `const model = new Model({});`

Comment: @kit okay I will give this a try